# Passing data from GUI to another class in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I am doing a project that consist on creating a Battleship Game.
I have the following classes:

- `Battleship` (main class)
- `Player`,
- `Game`,
- `Board`,
- `Visualisation` (GUI class where I have a `gridLayout` of `JButtons`) where the user press the `JButton` where want to insert the ship.

First of all a create a new `Game` with some parameters such as the size of the board. Then inside the class `Game` I do a new `Visualisation`. Inside this class I have done the `actionListener` and the `actionPerformed`.

My question is how I can pass the information, for example, of which `JButton` I have pressed (to insert the ship in that cell of the `gridLayout`) to the class `Game`? This is what I have:

```
Class Game
 private Player _user;
 private Player _computer;
```

And then I want to check the board of the `_user` if that positions are available to insert the ship. `_user.MethodOfClassPlayer();`

```
Class Player
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private Board _boardPlayer
```

```
Class Board
  private int size;
  private int[][] _board = null ;
```

Function actionPerformed

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < tUsuariCPU.length; i++ ){
            for ( int j = 0; j < tUsuariCPU[i].length; j++ ){
                if ( e.getSource() == tUsuariCPU[i][j] ){
                        buttonPressedUser(i,j);
                        JButton temp = (JButton) e.getSource() ;
                        temp.setBackground(java.awt.Color.ORANGE);
    }
```

I want to pass the information of the JButton pressed to Game class to know if for that Player that position is available or not for putting the ship. If it is available so I will paint the JButton
I hope you understand me.

Comment: I suggest you pass the battleship class in the constructor of GUI and keep a reference to it as a field in your GUI named parent: GUI(Battleship parent) and this.parent = parent. When a button is clicked, you can execute a function in the main class by simply doing: parent.myfunction()

Comment: you can use parameters in your constructor to pass some data, or you can just make the Visualisation class a dialog with a return function, when you click a button it save the "x and y of the cell" in an array and return the it to main class where it was called after you dispose it

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by already doing you action listener and such. Do you have an action connected to the buttons already? Can you add that code please?

Comment: ** the actionPerformed prints the JButton pressed. I want to pass the information of the button to the Game classe
***
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
for ( int i = 0; i < tUsuariCPU.length; i++ ){
                for ( int j = 0; j < tUsuariCPU[i].length; j++ ){
                    if ( e.getSource() == tUsuariCPU[i][j] ){
                            buttonPressedUser(i,j);
                            JButton temp = (JButton) e.getSource() ;
                            temp.setBackground(java.awt.Color.ORANGE);
            }

Answer (score 3):

Taking account of the other answer, you may want to use `Observers` and `Observable`. An Observable is a class that can be observed by one or several Observers. And an Observer can observe several Observables.

Example:

```
public class Visualisation extends JFrame {
    private Integer num;
    private A myInnerClass;

    public Visualisation(Observer o) {
        num = 8;
        myInnerClass = new A();
        myInnerClass.setObserver(o);
    }

    public onButtonPressed(Event e) {
        myInnerClass.notifyMyObservers();
    }

    public class A extends Observable {
        public A() {
        }

        public void notifyMyObservers() {
            this.setChanged();
            this.notifyObservers(num); // the parameter can be any object
        }
    }
}

public class B implements Observer {
    public B() {
    }

    public void update(Observable observed, Object arg) {
        if (observed instance of A) {
            if (arg instance of Integer) {
                // ... 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how you hook them up within an example main function

```
public static main(String[] args) {
    B observer = new B();
    Visualisation v = new Visualisation(observer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't see the relation with my project. So the JButtons have to be observables? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Not the JButtons but the class they are in. As the class you want to extends already extends `JFrame` you must create for example an innerclass which extends `Observable` into the class in which you extends `JFrame`. Then in your JFrame class you can call methods from your innerclass. Hope you understand.

Comment: So if I understand your class B is Game since he wants to access the JButton of Visualisation into Game.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dialog class like this:

```
public class Visualisation extends JDialog {

    private Board board;

    public Game(Frame owner, boolean modal) {
        super(owner, modal);

        // add a Listener to your button to dispose the dialog after you save your data in board
        JButton yourButton = new JButton();
        yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                board = ....;
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    public Board show(){
        setVisible(true);
        return Board ;
    }
}
```

and to call it in the game class use:

```
Visualisation visualisationDialog = new Visualisation(null, true);
Board board = visualisationDialog .show();
//do whatever you want with the board from here now
```